# How to access elements in java subarray without key but with index

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have an JSON that looks like this:

> {   "Message": "None",   "PDFS": [
>       [
>         "test.pdf",
>         "localhost/",
>         "777"
>       ],
>       [
>         "retest.pdf",
>         "localhost\",
>         "666"
>       ]   ],   "Success": true }

I'm trying to access the individual strings within the arrays but I'm having difficulty doing it as getString is requiring me to use a key and not indexes.

I've tried this to access the first string in each sub-array:

```
    JSONArray pdfArray = resultJson.getJSONArray("PDFS");
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdfArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject pdfObject = pdfArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String fileName = pdfObject.getString(0);
                    }
```

Comment: pdfArray further contains arrays, so you should do getJSONArray(i) instead of getJSONObject(i) ?

Answer (score 0):

Read the array as an array:

```
JSONArray array = pdfArray.getJSONArray(i);
String fileName = array.getString(0);
```